# Where can I find transform-origin's definition and how does transform-origin work?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a simple html with svg as below:

```html
<svg class="svg" style="border:1px solid black" width="200" height="200">
  <rect transform="translate(100, 100)" width="20" height="20" fill="red"></rect>
  <text transform="translate(100, 100) rotate(90)" transform-origin="0 0">TEST</text>
</svg>
```

The text element is rotated 90 degree in clockwise base on text's left-bottom corner (left-upper corner of red rect)

If I change text element to `<text x="50" y="50" transform="translate(50, 50) rotate(90)" transform-origin="0 0">TEST</text>`, the text is rotated to (0, 100) in svg. A reasonable guess is that transform-origin does not only affect "rotate" but also "translate". But I don't understand where "0 0" is in this situation, but it is not left-bottom corner of text element anymore.

I also don't understand how it works when I set "transform-origin" in percentage (e.g. 50% 50%) or text (e.g. left bottom). It doesn't work the way I thought it would. I have not been able to find a detailed tutorial on the definition of "transform-origin". Can someone with experience in this field give me some pointers? Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-box#svg_transform-origin_scoping

Comment: to understand transform-origin for percentages you also need to understand transform-box https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css-transforms/#transform-origin-property and https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css-transforms/#transform-box

Comment: Maybe this will help you understand: Since both the rect and the text are translated the same distance you can wrap them both in a group and translate the group instead. Now you can rotate the text:`transform="rotate(90 5 10)"` where `5 10` represent the center of rotation before the translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always easier in SVG contexts to read transformations as **transformations of the coordinate system**. Each of the steps builds on its predecessor. Your element

```
<text x="50" y="50" transform="translate(50, 50) rotate(90)" transform-origin="0 0">TEST</text>
```

can be understood as the following sequence:

- `translate(50, 50)`: Move the origin of the coordinate system to (50, 50) of the initial coordinate system
- `rotate(90)` and `transform-origin="0 0"`: Rotate the coordinate system found in the previous step by 90° clockwise around its own origin.
- `text x="50" y="50"`: Draw text at point (50, 50) of the coordinate system found in the previous step.

In relation to the initial coordinate system, the last one has its origin at (50, 50), the x-axis points left and the y-axis down. The blue lines show its position and orientation. Therefore, the point (50, 50) in that system is the same as (0, 100) in the initial coordinate system:

```html
<svg class="svg" style="border:1px solid black" width="200" height="200">
  <rect transform="translate(100, 100)" width="20" height="20" fill="red"></rect>
  <text x="50" y="50" transform="translate(50, 50) rotate(90)" transform-origin="0 0">TEST</text>
  <!-- draw the moved coordinate system -->
  <path transform="translate(50, 50) rotate(90)" transform-origin="0 0"
        d="M-5,0H100M0,-5V100" fill="none" stroke="blue" />
</svg>
```

So why does `transform-origin="0 0"` refer to the coordinate system? The [CSS Transforms](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css-transforms/#transform-origin-property) specification says:

> The value for the horizontal and vertical offset represent an offset from the top left corner of the **reference box**.

The reference box is defined by property [`transform-box`](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css-transforms/#transform-box). If not explicitely set, its initial value is `view-box`:

> Uses the nearest **SVG viewport** as reference box.

In your case, this is the box that defines the `<svg>` element and outlined by the black border, but with the defined sequence of transforms applied. (If there was a `viewBox` attribute present, it would represent a further [implicit transform](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/coords.html#ComputingAViewportsTransform), to be applied first.)

Comment: Thanks for all the answers and comments.
My original example is to experiment that transform-origin affects the whole transform, so an element with x=50, y=50 + translate(50,50) and an element with translate(100,100), although the initial position looks the same, but after the subsequent transform-origin & rotate have different results

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin: "[transform-origin] wraps a pair of translations around the element's other transformations", combined with the transform-box origin of the upper element (SVG) is used when positioning the element using x, y, I can understand how transform-origin affect transform now.